# How can I do this without breaking the MVC framework in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, model, view, model-view-controller

Sorry for what is a generic title. I'm not the best at titles.

Anyway the way Cake passes around data (as a hash) is pretty much the reason why I even need to ask this question. If when I passed a variable/obj from the controller to the view, it was an object that I can ask questions to (i.e. $duck->quack() ) rather than having it be an array/dictionary (i.e. $duck['Duck']['quack'] == true) this would be easy.

What I have in my app is a list of items that a user x can own or not. In certain views I display all the items in the database/app (i.e. paginate) and for each item I need to know if the logged in user owns it or not. To answer this question I need to do a query (due to a complicated HABTM relationship), which is done inside the Model. In other words my Item model has a function isOwnedByUser($user_id, $item_id) which is true if it is owned by user. I want to call this function from the view.

Naturally this is violating the MVC framework, but I'm not sure how else to do it. I had four ideas:

**Idea 1:**

Do this inside a helper:

```
App:Import('Model','Item');
$item = new Item();
$item->isOwnedByUser($user_id,$item_id);
```

and call the helper from the view (and pass in the $item_id and $user_id of course). But this REALLY violates the MVC framework.

**Idea 2:**

Create a action inside item_controller.php and call the action from the view using requestAction(). But I [heard that this was extremeley inefficent](http://mark-story.com/Posts/view/reducing-requestaction-use-in-your-cakephp-sites-with-fat-models)

Now these two ideas I found when I was [looking](http://www.nabble.com/Does-calling-model-methods-from-elements-break-MVC-pattern--td19784908.html) for a solution to my problem but according to them those two ideas are bad so I came up with two more solutions:

**Idea 3:**

When returning the paginated data to the view, I can make sure that all items have a 'user_id' key so that I can check the key in the view against the logged in user's id to see if he/she owns item. But this would require a) me to re-write pagination b) very ugly queries especially for certain views (search), c) overall ugliness and slowness. So I decided to abandon this idea

**Idea 4:**

Every time a view needs to know if an item is owned by user, I'll just pass along another array from the controller that contains ALL the items a user owns and in the view you can just use in_array() to check if user owns said item. Of course the problem to this is obvious: what if the user has lots of items?

In short I'm stuck at this and I have no clue where to go from here and I'd appreciate all help! Thanks!

Comment: I should also add that the way Cake handles HABTM relationships also sucks. Really sucks. But that has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd combine 3 and 4.

In your action, after you get all the paginated items:

```
$items = $this->paginate('Item');
```

Get their IDs and combine that with the user ID to fetch all the user's items.

```
$itemIds = Set::extract('/Item/id', $items);

$usersItems = $this->Item->User->find
    (
        'all',
        array
        (
            'conditions' => array
            (
                'User.id' = $userId,
                'Item.id' => $itemIds
            ),
            'fields' => array('User.id', 'Item.id')
        )
);
```

Now you can set the $usersItems in a format you prefer and set both that and $items for the view. That would bring you to your option 4 and in_array(), except it would probably be Set::extract() or Set::check().

Something like this should do it:

```
if (Set::extract(sprintf('/Item[id=%s]', $itemId), $usersItems))
{
    // user has the item
}
```

(I wrote this from my memory so... you know what to do if it fails :))

Edit:

Alternatively, you can do something like this (it should be faster than the above, just make sure to move `Set::extract()` out of the loop):

```
$usersItemIds = Set::extract('/Item/id', $usersItems);

if (in_array($itemId, $usersItemIds))
{
    // user has the item
}
```

Comment: Sorry it took me nearly a day to reply but this works great! I totally didn't know about the Set utility and now I can refactor a large bunch of code that was inefficiently written! 

Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Set class is one of the best things in cake, and somehow unknown to the general public. So, spread the word! :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it seems like maybe the ACL component would be a good option here.